# Triangle Wave Generation

Tags: voltage, generator, wave

What would be the best way to generate a triangle wave that can operate at 250kHz @ 4V peak-to-peak? I have tried the following circuit:

[image: Triangle Wave Generator Circuit]

However, the best I could obtain was a 4mV peak to peak voltage at 160kHz despite mathematically calculating resistor and capacitor values, and trial and error.

Comment: You could start by using a modern high-performance opamp, instead of the antiquated LM741.

Comment: Oh I forgot to state that I am using a TLO74 op amp in both applications

Comment: Without knowing your component values, especially R4, R5, and C2, there is simply no way to know if the circuit is working correctly. Voltage supply values are needed as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a modern op-amp for this, I'm going to guess that your problem lies with the value of the integrating capacitor C2.

As you already figured out, R1 & C1 set the square-wave frequency.  C2 integrates that square wave into a triangle wave.  But the value of C2 depends on the frequency that you are trying to generate.

Given that you said that you are only getting about 4 mV output, I'm guessing that C2 is somewhere between 100 to 1000 times too large.

You also don't mention your supply voltage - making C2 about 1000 times smaller should theoretically give you about 4V P-P, assuming that your supply voltage is high enough.

Also ensure that R5 is a very large value - somewhere between 1 - 10 MOhms.  Its only purpose to provide DC feedback to IC2.  If R5 is too small, it reduces the gain.